# Compute the average of count result

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I am trying to find the average number of products/store. I want something like this:

```
Store       Avg.Products
Store 1     100
Store 2     20
```

Store table: StoreId

Products table: Productid, Pname, StoreId

If there are 100 total products and by using count i got 9 products for store 1 i want 9/100 for store 1 and similarly for the other stores

I tried:

```
Select avg(counts) from(Select count(*) AS counts
   FROM Store Join Product ON Store.Id = product.StoreId Group By Store.id)table1
```

But this just gives me a single value. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to group the outer query by ***store name*** and cast `AVG` parameter to `float` to allow it to return non-integer values:

```
SELECT storeName, avg(CAST(counts AS float)) FROM 
    (Select count(*) AS counts, S.Name as storeName
        FROM Store S JOIN Product P ON S.Id = P.StoreId Group By S.id, S.Name) table1
    GROUP BY storeName
```

It may be not the best way to do this, but it should return the expected results.

**UPDATE**

I've verified the answer and updated the code with a fixed version. Let me know if it works for Your case.

**UPDATE II**

According to Your comment, You would like to calculate the number of products for each shop name and then divide it by total number of products in the database.
If this has to be one query, You can do it like this:

```
SELECT S.Name as storeName, CAST(count(*) AS float) / MIN(T.TotalCount) AS AVGToTotalProductsCount
    FROM Store S JOIN Product P ON S.Id = P.StoreId
        JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS TotalCount FROM Product) T ON 1=1
    GROUP BY S.Name
```

However, if the query can be split into multiple queries, You may be able to calculate it like this:

```
DECLARE @totalNumOfProducts INT   
SELECT @totalNumOfProducts = COUNT(1) FROM Product

SELECT S.Name as storeName, CAST(COUNT(*) AS float) / @totalNumOfProducts AS AVGToTotalProductsCount
    FROM Store S JOIN Product P ON S.Id = P.StoreId
    GROUP BY S.Name
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Why does this query return the same values that the count of products return.?

Comment: In some cases it should. When You have only one shop (one shop.Id) with a specific name, the average for this shop name is the same as number of products in it, so both queries may return the same value. In other cases the vlaues may differ.

Comment: From what I understand the average for each group is being calculates as  numberOfProductsInThatGroup/Total number of products?

Comment: As I understand it, You wanted it to be calculated per shop name, so the average is `number of products in shops with specific shop name / number of shops with this specific name`.

Comment: Oops. No. For instance there is only one store with that name. Walmart was a bad example. I want the Number of Products in one store/ Number of total products in the database

Comment: So if there are 100 total products and  by using count i got 9 products for store 1 i want 9/100 for store 1 and similarly for other store

Comment: Does it have to be one query or it can be spit it into multiple queries?

Comment: I've posted SQL samples for both cases in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  In your derived table, get a `COUNT(ProductID)` and `GROUP BY StoreID`.  Then `JOIN` that back to your main query on `StoreID`, and do the `AVG` aggregation:

```
SELECT S.Name, AVG(ProductCount)
FROM   Stores S
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ProductID) as ProductCount, StoreID
            FROM   Stores S
            GROUP BY StoreID) P on S.ID = P.StoreID
GROUP BY S.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making it too hard.  Just count the products that result from the join.

```
select s.StoreID, s.Name, count(p.ProductID) ProductCount
from store s
    join Product p on p.StoreID=s.StoreID
group by s.StoreID, s.Name
order by count(p.ProductID);
```